# std::getline issue when parsing lines with stringstream library

Tags: c++

I am getting an error while trying to parse a stringstream when reading from a file, I cannot seem to figure what the issue is.

the error I am receiving is:

```
  no matching function for call to 'getline'
  std::getline(parse_input, intensity, ',');
```

this repeats for each variable I am trying to parse.

the following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  std::fstream fs;
  fs.open("test.dat");

  std::string* configuration_record;
  std::string temp_count;
  size_t no_of_records;

  if(!fs.is_open())
  {
    std::cerr << "File failed to open" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    while(!fs.eof())
    {
      std::getline(fs, temp_count);
      no_of_records++;
    }
    fs.clear();
    fs.seekp(0);
  }

  std::string stimulation_type;
  std::string stimulation_name;
  double intensity;
  double frequency;
  double duration;
  std::string location;

  configuration_record = new std::string[no_of_records];

  for(size_t i=0; i<no_of_records; i++)
  {
    std::getline(fs, configuration_record[i]);
  }

  for(size_t i=0; i<no_of_records; i++)
  {
    size_t found;
    found = configuration_record[i].find("stim");
    if(found != std::string::npos)
    {

      std::stringstream parse_input(configuration_record[i]);
      std::getline(parse_input, stimulation_type, ',');
      std::getline(parse_input, stimulation_name, ',');
      std::getline(parse_input, location, ',');
      std::getline(parse_input, intensity, ',');
      std::getline(parse_input, frequency, ',');
      std::getline(parse_input, duration, ',');

      std::cout << stimulation_name << "," <<location << intensity << "," << frequency << "," << duration
      << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {

      std::stringstream parse_input(configuration_record[i]);
      std::getline(parse_input, stimulation_type, ',');
      std::getline(parse_input, stimulation_name, ',');
      std::getline(parse_input, intensity, ',');
      std::getline(parse_input, duration, ',');

      std::cout << stimulation_name << "," << intensity << "," << duration
      << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getline`will read a line of input as a string, not as a `double`.

Comment: I think you need use >> or similar mechanism for parsing. getline just reads line from input.

Comment: thanks @BoPersson, the name "STRING"stream says it all.

Comment: The string in question is the second parameter to `std::getline()`, not the first. The first parameter to `std::getline()` is a `std::istream`. Which could be a `std::istringstream`, or a `std::ifstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declarations for getline from the [manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) are:

```
istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str, char delim);
istream& getline (istream&& is, string& str, char delim);
istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str);
istream& getline (istream&& is, string& str);
```

As you see, they accept an `istream` ([stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is valid), however the second argument has to be a `string`, so when you pass `double` (`intensity`, `frequency` and `duration`), you are calling an inexistent function. 
you can use a temporary string and then save it to a double, using [stod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/):

```
std::string temp;
double intensity;
std::getline(parse_input, temp, ',');
intensity= std::stod (temp);
```